# Configure Spring Zuul to do an OAuth2 "resource owner password grant" for requests with a Basic Authentication header

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication, netflix-zuul, netflix

I have created a very basic Spring Cloud Zuul application to act as a token relay to a resource server. This is extremely simple to do for `authorization_code` grant. The below does exactly what I need:

```
package zuul;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableZuulProxy
public class RelayProxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RelayProxy.class, args);
    }

}
```

And in the application.yml (my authorization server runs on port 9999):

```
server:
    port: 8000

security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/token
            userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/authorize
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
            clientId: client
            clientSecret: secret
        resource:
            jwt:
                key-uri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/token_key

zuul:
    routes:
        resource:
            path: /resource/**
            url: http://localhost:8002/
```

To allow a legacy system that only supports Basic Authentication to get access to the resource server, I would like a request with a basic authentication header to be intercepted and a password grant performed to obtain and relay the access token. I have tried to configure this using Spring Security / OAuth2 configuration, but was unable to get it to work. The zuul filter below is what I am currently using and it works fine, but I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the same result through the correct Spring configuration:

```
public class PasswordGrantZuulFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext clientContext;

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        String header = ctx.getRequest().getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        return header != null && header.toLowerCase().startsWith("basic");
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        if (clientContext.getAccessToken() == null) {

            String header = ctx.getRequest().getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

            String base64Credentials = header.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
            String credentials = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Credentials), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            final String[] values = credentials.split(":", 2);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
            headers.put(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, Collections.singletonList("Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((clientId + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes())));

            MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            map.add("grant_type", "password");
            map.add("username", values[0]);
            map.add("password", values[1]);

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

            ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> response = new RestTemplate().postForEntity(accessTokenUri, request, OAuth2AccessToken.class);
            clientContext.setAccessToken(response.getBody());
        }

        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, OAuth2AccessToken.BEARER_TYPE + " " + clientContext.getAccessToken().getValue());

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: code is clear but your question is not clear?